# Rewriting URL with nginx my rewrite not working

Tags: nginx

I'm in the process of learning URL rewrites with nginx and would like to know why the example below is not working

I have the following URL

http://example.com/listings.php?city=Fayetteville

I have the following URL rewire rule

```
rewrite ^/listings\.php\?city=(.*)$ http://google.com permanent;
```

which I though should change the URL to google.com when I visit http://example.com/listings.php?city=Fayetteville , but nothing happens. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Anything from the `?` onwards (the query string) is not part of the normalised URI used to match the regular expressions in `rewrite` and `location` directives.

Comment: Do you want to do that for all listing.php or only when city is Fayetteville? As @RichardSmith mentioned request uri doesn't get arguments

Comment: @TarunLalwani I was just playing with it for learning purposes. But at the end I want http://example.com/listings.php?city=AnyCityName to become http://example.com/AnyCityName is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You would use something like below

```
location = /listings.php {
    if ($arg_city) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /$arg_city;
   }
}
```

**Edit-1**

You can handle it in your config like below

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/example.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                set $test '';
            if ($request_uri ~* "^/listing\.php") {
                    set $test "listing";
                }

                if ($arg_city) {
                    set $test "$test-city";
                }

                if ($test = "listing-city")
                {
                    return 301 /$arg_city;
                }

                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

Comment: I was getting a syntax error on "if (arg_city) {" so I changed it to "if ($arg_city) {" and the syntax error went away. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo

Comment: Now when I go to http://example.com/listings.php?city=Mobile I get a 404. A bit lost as how this supposed to work. It's my first time working with URL rewrites

Comment: That is because outside else you are not doing anything. You need to pass it to php-fpm when this is not the case

Comment: This is the relevant server block https://pastebin.com/6Kif04RF I should figure it out if I can see an example of this. How would we make the rewrite work in my case?

Comment: @Arya, please check the edit, might have to tweak in case of issues as I didn't get a chance to test it on nginx

Comment: There are no errors when I restart nginx, but it does not seem the URL rewrite is working.

Comment: @Arya, please check the updated config. This has been tested and works for me